# converting a Worm the Walks from 3.5/pathfinder to 2ED

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, adnd-2e

I am writing a mod for 2ED and really wanted to include something I found in both the 3.0/3.6 Epic Level Handbook and a Pathfinder Bestiary.  I wanted to include a Worm that Walks as the main boss, but am having problems with the conversion to 2ED, as it does not exist in any 2ED books that I am aware of.  Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question is a bit unclear as it stands. Are you asking "can someone homebrew this monster for me?" or "Does someone know of an existing homebrew of this monster" or even just "How do I homebrew monsters to a different edition?". Each question would have a different answer. Can you edit the question to reflect what exactly you'd like to see?

Comment: Also, I think the "Worm That Walks" essentially _replaced_ and _anthropomorphised_ the terrifying druid spell, AD&D 2nd Edition version, Spell _Creeping Doom_.